# How to install aspell (spell check library) on fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, spell-check

I want to install aspell library (http://aspell.net/) on fedora. GNU Aspell is a Free and Open Source spell checker.

Answer (score 2):

`yum install aspell` as root